# python webkit signals

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, position, mouse

I would like to use webkit to create a simple web browser with some special functions. In particular, I would like to have a function that adds a word to a file, if I click on that word. Now, I already have the browser, but I could not figure out how I would read out the word at the mouse position. Could someone suggest either a solution, or some material on this?

Thanks,

v923z

Comment: On a serious note - why not just write a browser extension?

Comment: Because first, I don't know how to write an extension, and second, I want to run the application on a small device (tablet), which would be quite unhappy with firefox:) As to what I have tried, I have read through the signals of a webview, but that would not tell me what I am supposed to do, once I caught the signal...

Answer (score 0):

The gtk webkit has limited possibility to talk with python.

There is a guide on doing so here:

http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

It involves sending javascript to the browser, and for the browser to communicate with python to change the title of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they [fixed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137116) ability to use the selected signal, so something like this may work...

```
mywebview.connect('selection-changed', nameofmyfunction)
```

and observe arguments passed to nameofmyfunction().